# Get time zone information of the system in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the default timezone (PST) of my system from Python.  What's the best way to do that?  I'd like to avoid forking another process.

Comment: related: [get local time zone name on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62330675/10197418)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check out the Python [Time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) Module.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print(strftime("%z", gmtime()))
```

Pacific Standard Time

Comment: are we looking at different documents or is it `'%Z'`?

Comment: @ SilentGhost: "%z" and '%z' are exactly the same in Python.

Comment: @ SilentGhost: Ah, my apologies, missed that. Just ran a new test and both %z and %Z both work in Python 2.6.

Comment: **but produce different output**.

Comment: >>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> print strftime('%z', gmtime())
Pacific Standard Time
>>> print strftime('%Z', gmtime())
Pacific Standard Time

I disagree.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime Also mentions nothing about case on the %Z format.

Comment: well, 1. on my machine they produce different outputs; 2. docs don't say anything about lower-case z, because only upper-case Z is a valid literal and lower case is not supposed to be used. http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior here are some details of what lower-case z produced (even in time module).

Comment: furthermore, docs state (http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#id2) that use of %Z is deprecated.

Comment: Also check out [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) and [tzlocal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) that helps with this. %z (and %Z) produce non-standard, ambiguous platform dependent strings that aren't very useful.

Comment: In Python 2.7 on Linux, `%Z` produces TZ acronym eg. `CET`, while `%z` produces offset, eg. `+0100`

Comment: This gave me GMT, which is not the system timezone on my machine. The `import time; time.tzname` solution gave me (EST, EDT) which is correct for my purposes.

Comment: This gave me the wrong timezone (again, GMT) in Python 2, but the correct one in Python 3.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MBvbL9sVUhLyA2KN9Wa67yoBISbDy8cnSVyq7HatgmKnLOPEqyTr6Qd427Rxulz6rpcN0uB4r9OYqzdYiGEfyJ3cUgMBbjagA-MQ_65loDDG8aRiefyGltLx2V51yDRFLYSEP5IN

Comment: This is incorrect, GMT gives gmt time, you're supposed to use `localtime`

Answer (score 152):

This should work:

```
import time
time.tzname
```

`time.tzname` returns a tuple of two strings: The first is the name of the local non-DST timezone, the second is the name of the local DST timezone.

Example return: `('MST', 'MDT')`

Comment: To take this one further, you can use `time.tzname[time.daylight]` to get the name of the current timezone, accounting for daylight saving time.

Comment: Again, 'time.daylight' does not indicate that DST is active. It merely indicates whether or not DST is observed by the timezone. You're looking for 'time.localtime().tm_isdst'.

Comment: Just to add for Windows users, the values for timezone was defined in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\`

Comment: [`time.tzname` may return a wrong value](http://bugs.python.org/issue22798) if the local timezone had different abbreviations in the past (Python uses values from January, July or the current (import/`tzset()` time) value). `tzlocal` module could be used to get the correct tzname for a given date.

Comment: is there a way to get the name? like Asia/Tehran ?

Comment: @senaps : Yes, `d=datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("US/Pacific"))` and `print(d.tzinfo.zone)`. It only works if the timezone was assigned in the original datetime object and not deduced.

Answer (score 43):

I found this to work well:

```
import datetime
tz_string = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzname()
```

For me this was able to differentiate between daylight savings and not.

From Python 3.6 you can do:

```
tz_string = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzname()
```

Or

```
tz_string = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo
```

Reference with more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079819/4549682

Comment: as from python 3.6 you can just write `tz_string = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzname()`

Also if you want to get more than just the timezone's name you can use:
`datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo`

Answer (score 41):

Gives a UTC offset like in ThomasH's answer, but takes daylight savings into account.

```
>>> import time
>>> offset = time.timezone if (time.localtime().tm_isdst == 0) else time.altzone
>>> offset / 60 / 60 * -1
-9
```

The value of `time.timezone` or `time.altzone` is in seconds West of UTC (with areas East of UTC getting a negative value). This is the opposite to how we'd actually like it, hence the * -1.

`time.localtime().tm_isdst` will be zero if daylight savings is currently not in effect (although this may not be correct if an area has recently changed their daylight savings law).

EDIT: marr75 is correct, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: To be safe, I think the offset check should be reversed (altzone if dst = 1 else timezone). If DST status is somehow unknown, `tm_isdst` will be `-1`, and the current code would default to `altzone` in this case. For regions that don't use DST, this value is never correct, so `timezone` should probably be the fallback. (I'm not sure if `-1` is actually possible output from `localtime` though)

Comment: [all altzone, timezone-based solution may fail in some edge cases](http://bugs.python.org/issue1647654)

Answer (score 12):

The code snippets for calculating offset are incorrect, see http://bugs.python.org/issue7229.

The correct way to handle this is:

```
def local_time_offset(t=None):
    """Return offset of local zone from GMT, either at present or at time t."""
    # python2.3 localtime() can't take None
    if t is None:
        t = time.time()

    if time.localtime(t).tm_isdst and time.daylight:
        return -time.altzone
    else:
        return -time.timezone
```

This is in all likelihood, not the exact question that the OP asked, but there are two incorrect snippets on the page and time bugs suck to track down and fix.

Comment: 1. if you know `tm_isdst`; you don't need to check `daylight` 2. [all `altzone`, `timezone`-based solution may fail in some edge cases](http://bugs.python.org/issue1647654)

Comment: This works for me on both python 2.6 and 3.6. Also important to note that the offset is in *seconds*.

Answer (score 12):

For Python 3.6+ this can be easily achieved by following code:

```py
import datetime
local_timezone = datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo

print(local_timezone)
```

But with Python < 3.6 calling `astimezone()` on naive datetime doesn't work. So we've to do it in a slightly different way.

So for Python 3.x,

```py
import datetime
local_timezone = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo

print(local_timezone)
```

Sample Output:
On Netherlands Server(Python 3.6.9):
`CEST`
On Bangladesh Server(Python 3.8.2):
`+06`

More details can be found on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720319/python-figure-out-local-timezone).

Answer (score 4):

To obtain timezone information in the form of a [`datetime.tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) object, use [`dateutil.tz.tzlocal()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzlocal):

```py
from dateutil import tz
myTimeZone = tz.tzlocal()
```

This object can be used in the `tz` parameter of [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
localisedDatetime = datetime.now(tz = tz.tzlocal())
```

or the `tz` parameter of `datetime` object via [`datetime.datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
unlocalisedDatetime = datetime.now()
localisedDatetime = unlocalisedDatetime.astimezone(tz = tz.tzlocal())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import tzlocal
tz_info = tzlocal.get_localzone() # 'US/Central' or 'Asia/Calcutta'
dt = datetime.now()        # 2023-01-15 15:17:24.412430
print(tz_info.localize(dt) # 2023-01-15 15:17:24.412430-06:00
```

with `tzlocal` we will be able to get the local timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Getting offset from UTC as `timedelta`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now = datetime.now()
now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - now.astimezone(timezone.utc)
```

Or like this (more obscure but also works):

```py
datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo.utcoffset(None)
```

Both solutions give the same result. For example: `datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there are multiple time zone formats, namely:

1. [IANA Time Zone Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones): "TZ Identifier" (e.g. `"Africa/Addis_Ababa"`)
2. IANA Time Zone Database: "abbreviation" (e.g. `"EAT"`)
3. [Microsoft Time Zone Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11) (e.g. `"E. Africa Standard Time"`)
4. UTC offset (e.g. `"+03:00"` or `"UTC+03:00"`)
5. The [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country codes are sometimes also used to reference time zones but these do not map cleanly (e.g. `"ET"`, `"ETH"`, or `231`)

Here's how to get all time zones and the system time zone, in all these formats:

| Database Name | Example | List all time zones | Get system time zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IANA Time Zone Identifiers | `'Asia/Bangkok'` | `import zoneinfo as zi; zi.available_timezones()` or `pytz.all_timezones` | `import tzlocal as tzl; str(tzl.get_localzone())` |
| IANA Time Zone Abbreviations | `'ICT'` | In Python I'm not sure how; see the IANA wiki page for a list | [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067621/) |
| Microsoft Time Zone Index | `'SE Asia Standard Time'` | ** Note 1 | `time.tzname[0]` |
| Time zone offset | `'+07:00'` | N/A | ** Note 2 |

** Note 1: in Powershell,

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones()
```

** Note 2: in Python,

```py
iana_tz = str(tzlocal.get_localzone())
pytz_tz = pytz.timezone(iana_tz)
offset_str = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(pytz_tz).strftime("%z")
offset_str = offset_str[:3] + ':' + offset_str[3:]
```