# Python datetime formatting conversion

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

If I have a datetime object, like -

```
2012-03-10
```

How would I convert it into the following string format -

```
Sat, 10 Mar 2012 00:00:00 EDT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datetime.strptime("2012-03-10", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EDT")
```

Sorry about the primitive way of adding the timezone. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720319/python-figure-out-local-timezone) for better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> a = dt.now().replace(tzinfo = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
>>> a.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
'Fri, 09 Mar 2012 20:02:51 EST'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7+, using `dateutil`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

s = '2012-03-10'
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s).replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('US/Eastern'))
print(dt.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'))
>>> 'Sat, 10 Mar 2012 00:00:00 EST'
```

Python 3.9+, using `zoneinfo`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

s = '2012-03-10'
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
```