# Python datetime.now() with timezone

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone

I have a timezone which is float (for example 4.0).
I want to construct `datetime` with given timezone.

I tried this,

```
datetime.now(timezone)
```

but it throws

```
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'float'
```

So I wonder how can I make `tzinfo` from float?

Comment: I'm assuming your float is +- hours from gmt?

Comment: Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.2 or newer, you need to create a [`datetime.timezone()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects); it takes an offset as a [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

timezone_offset = -8.0  # Pacific Standard Time (UTC−08:00)
tzinfo = timezone(timedelta(hours=timezone_offset))
datetime.now(tzinfo)
```

For earlier Python versions, it'll be easiest to use an external library to define a timezone object for you.

The [`dateutil` library](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) includes objects to take a numerical offset to create a timezone object:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset

timezone_offset = -8.0  # Pacific Standard Time (UTC−08:00)
tzinfo = tzoffset(None, timezone_offset * 3600)  # offset in seconds
datetime.now(tzinfo)
```

Comment: Wow, surely there must be a less hard-coded way to go. I'm in the UK: UTC+1 during the "summer" months, but UTC during the others. I want the script to work out which applies automatically.

Comment: @mikerodent: The UK is **not** using UTC in winter, nor `UTC + 1` in summer. The UK uses `BTS` (summer) and `GTM` (winter), respectively, which happen to match `UTC+1` and `UTC` respectively but also define the rules of when they transition from one to the other. If you can use `pytz`, I'd use `Europe/London` and get full summertime / wintertime support. Or use Python 3.9 and the new [`zoneinfo` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) and the same name.

Comment: @mikerodent: e.g. `datetime(2022, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/London")).isoformat()` produces `2022-10-31T12:00:00+00:00`, while `datetime(2022, 5, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/London")).isoformat()` gives `2022-05-31T12:00:00+01:00`, note the offsets in those strings.

Comment: Thanks. But still hard-coded (i.e. the location string), although much better, obviously. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079819/595305 (including several of the comments). And also the comment to the question there which says the wish to find the local area automatically is questionable.

Comment: @mikerodent: You didn't mention anything about detecting the local timezone. That's a different problem again, but solvable with platform-specific options; e.g. on Linux just read `/etc/timezone`. The answer there is decent, it gives `GMT` on my Mac, which is perfectly accurate. The `tzlocal` module implements those platform-specific paths (albeit by reading `/etc/localtime` for the definition, which is a symlink to the timezone definition named by `/etc/timezone`; it uses `/etc/timezone` as one of the options to get you the name). On my Mac, again, this produces `Europe/London`.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to use **[pytz](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/)**, as it could be simpler.

According to the description:

> This library allows accurate and cross platform timezone calculations using Python 2.4 or higher. It also solves the issue of ambiguous times at the end of daylight saving time, which you can read more about in the Python Library Reference

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz

>>> datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 12, 20, 59, 54, 579812, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("Europe/Oslo"))
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 12, 22, 0, 4, 911480, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Oslo' CET+1:00:00 STD>)

>>> [tz for tz in pytz.common_timezones if tz.startswith("US")]
['US/Alaska',
 'US/Arizona',
 'US/Central',
 'US/Eastern',
 'US/Hawaii',
 'US/Mountain',
 'US/Pacific']
```

Comment: pytz is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

One-liner using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) standard library of **Python 3.9**:

```
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> datetime.now(ZoneInfo('US/Pacific'))
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 21, 59, 10, 422603, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Pacific'))
```

Answer (score 8):

From Python 3.6 onwards you can use the `astimezone` method on a `datetime` object to get a timezone-aware `datetime` object based on the user's locale:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat()
'2023-05-25T17:52:38.524753-07:00'
```

Comment: Maybe not the answer OP was looking for (seeing that they had the timezone as float), but exactly what I was looking for when I landed here

Comment: Also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 brought the [IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) support (`pytz`-like) as [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#using-zoneinfo).

It's advisable using the IANA names instead of static UTC offsets due daylight saving time.