# Getting timezone of browser

Tags: python

I am working on a feature that displays the last saved time of a blog post based on the timezone of the user's browser. In Javascript I can use
`var currentTime = new Date();`.

I want to do the same in python. Searching on SO, I found

```
import time
import datetime
import dateutil

now = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time())
tzlocal = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()
print tzlocal.tzname(now)
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332721/how-should-i-serialize-a-dateutil-tz-tzlocal-object). However, it returns 'PDT' instead of my browser timezone which I set to 'EST' which is also what `var currentTime = new Date();` returns (EST). What am I missing here?

Comment: May I know the Python version you are using.. looking at the `print` statement it should be `2.x` but still want to confirm

Comment: I'm on python version 2.7

Comment: What this statement gives you - `datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzlocal()).tzname()`

Comment: You have to do it from the browser's side. for example, output the UTC version from python side and then convert that according to the user's local time using js (on page load).

Comment: @anuragal it returns 'PDT'