# In Python 3.8, how do I convert a timezone to words?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I'm using Python 3.8.  I have an expression that gives me the local timezone

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0))).astimezone().tzinfo
```

It prints out "EDT".  How do I take the above and convert it to words?  E.g. I would want the result to be something like

```
America/New_York
```

Not sure what the proper terminology is for the above, but it's what you get if you run this in a shell

```
ls -la /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f8-9
```

Comment: did you have a look at `tzlocal`, as e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057968/get-system-local-timezone-in-python)? On Linux, I think it should work with the `dateutil` method; on Windows the `tzlocal` package works fine for me (uses `pytz`) but needs to fall back on some more rigorous methods (than read from /etc/localtime) to extract the name of the local time zone.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to -- "datetime.now(tzlocal())"?  That doesn't print out timezone in words if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives me what you want on my machine:

```
#!pip install tzlocal
from tzlocal import get_localzone
str(get_localzone())
'Europe/Moscow'
```

Alternatively:

```
from subprocess import getstatusoutput
getstatusoutput("ls -la /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f7-9")[1]
'Europe/Moscow'
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want the [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) or the [abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) that indecates the UTC offset, you could use the `tzlocal` package (currently uses `pytz` internally):

```
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone

# a datetime object aware of the local time zone:
dt = datetime.now().astimezone(get_localzone())

# the __str__ method of the tzinfo gives you the IANA name:
str(dt.tzinfo)
>>> 'Europe/Berlin'

# the _tzname attribute is the abbreviated form:
dt.tzname() # == dt.tzinfo._tzname
>>> 'CEST'

# ...which is what you also get from strftime('%Z'):
dt.strftime('%Z')
>>> 'CEST'
```

Side note: using `dateutil.tz.tzlocal` did *not* work out for me, neither in a Windows nor in a Unix environment. It just allows to get the abbreviated tz name, not the full IANA name.