# Finding local time zone using Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I want to find my local time zone and then return the time zone name (cet, est etc.) using Python and my location so that I can just find it without entering any additional information except for the location of my pc (which I want to find using GPS and not manually adding it)

```
import say
import datetime

def timezone():
    timezone = datetime.datetime.now()
    timezonename = timezone.strftime("%Z")
    timezoneoffset = timezone.strftime("%z")
    say.praten(f"the timezone is {timezonename} which is {timezoneoffset} off UTC")
```

I used this but this doesn't return anything with the datetime import
the say command is from a different file for text to speech

everyone is revering me to this post : [Get system local timezone in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057968/get-system-local-timezone-in-python)
but I tried this and I got the full name of the time zone (Europe Berlin) but I want the 3 letter name (cet in my case)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get system local timezone in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057968/get-system-local-timezone-in-python)

Comment: Note that abbreviated time zone names such as CET or EST are ambiguous. Use IANA time zone names instead to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the time module to get your local timezone:

```
import time
print(time.tzname)
```

This gets you a tuple like `('CET', 'CEST')`.

Comment: currently active would be `time.localtime().tm_zone`

Answer (score 0):

borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700070/10197418) to the linked Q&A, you can also do

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt_local = datetime.now().astimezone()

print(dt_local.isoformat(timespec="seconds"))
print(dt_local.strftime("%Z"))

# on my machine:
# 2022-11-09T18:50:13+01:00
# CET
```

The important part is to make the datetime object aware of the local time zone (setting of your machine) by calling `.astimezone()`.