# How to get the original local machine time zone in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

In Django you have a [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) setting, which, as I understand, somehow patches the standard date and time packages in runtime, making them think the application is working in the time zone specified. As a result, generic Python [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720319/python-figure-out-local-timezone) for determining local time zone do not work (they just show the configured time zone).

I can evaluate the link of `/etc/localtime` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634136/947012) or use another Linux-specific method but I am concerned about the portability issue, as some developers run the app on Windows.

Can I find out in a platform independent way what was the original time zone on the machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "local machine"? Are we talking about the server the Django app is running on or the client machine browsing the app?

Comment: @Selcuk I should have been more specific: the time zone settings in the OS user account which runs the Django server application.

Comment: Django sets an environment variable but doesn't patch anything. You can try the [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) package to get the server timezone on both windows and unix.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Maybe I am missing something, but like I posted in my question, every single method by the provided link (including tzlocal package) returns the zone configured in `TIME_ZONE`. I don't know how else to explain it, other than by altering the standard packages. E.g. `datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo` is showing me the correct time zone in pure Python, but is showing the `TIME_ZONE` time zone when running the Django app.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry the documentation gives some insight on that: "On Unix environments, Django sets the os.environ['TZ'] variable to the time zone you specify in the TIME_ZONE setting". This is what seems to affect work of the standard date/time packages. The question is how to fallback to the default method of getting time zone, not affecting other places where date/time functions are used.

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a948d9df394aafded78d72b1daa785a0abfeab48/django/conf/__init__.py#L169) the issue is that Django is calling [`time.tzset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzset). Not sure how you can access the original value.

Comment: since `time.tzset()` is only for Unix systems, what does django do on Windows? Anyways, a (hacky) work-around could be to use geo-location, e.g. `os.system('curl http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone')` - note however that this will not necessarily return the time zone of the machine, just its location.

Answer (score 0):

As there were no answers, I will post a workaround here.

Though we cannot recover the initial time zone (without affecting the current settings), we can obtain and save it before Django's initialization. For example:

1. For running locally, we can augment `manage.py`:

```
cmd = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else ""
if cmd == "runserver":
    from tzlocal import get_localzone
    os.environ['MACHINE_TIME_ZONE'] = get_localzone().tzname(None)
# ...
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

2. For production, the way depends on how you launch the application. For example, if you are using Gunicorn, you can put it into `gunicorn.conf.py` or `wsgi.py`. The main thing is tu put it somewhere before loading Django libraries:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
os.environ['MACHINE_TIME_ZONE'] = get_localzone().tzname(None)
```

Later you can access this environment variable to retrieve the value.