# How can I convert a date/time string in local time into UTC in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I am trying to write a function that will convert a string date/time from local time to UTC in Python.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111056/get-time-zone-information-of-the-system-in-python), you can use `time.tzname` to get some forms of the local timezone, but I have not found a way to use this in any of the datetime conversion methods. For example, [this article](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/) shows there are a couple of things you can do with `pytz` and `datetime` to convert times, but all of them have timezones that are hardcoded in and are of different formats than what `time.tzname`returns.

Currently I have the following code to translate a string-formatted time into milliseconds (Unix epoch):

```
local_time = time.strptime(datetime_str, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") # expects UTC, but I want this to be local
dt = datetime.datetime(*local_time[:6])
ms = int((dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1000)
```

However, this is expecting the time to be input as UTC. Is there a way to convert the string formatted time as if it were in the local timezone? Thanks.

**Essentially, I want to be able to do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79877/3345085) does, but instead of hard-coding in "America/Los_Angeles", I want to be able to dynamically specify the local timezone.**

Comment: from time import gmtime, strftime

LocTime = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
GMTime = strftime("%Y %m %d T %H:%M:%S (GMT)", gmtime())

print "Local :",LocTime
print "UTC :",GMTime

Comment: you want to convert from local time 2 utc ?

Comment: you can get timezone with : tz = strftime("%Z")

Comment: @Mr.zero Yes, I want to convert from local time to utc. Yes, I can also get that with time.tzname, but how can I use that to do a conversion from that timezone that it returns to UTC? For example, maybe using pytz's astimezone() method.

Comment: @Mr.zero I also want to be able to pass any time I want, not just using 'now'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want this :

```
from time import strftime,gmtime,mktime,strptime

# you can pass any time you want
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(mktime(strptime("Thu, 30 Jun 2016 03:12:40", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))))

# and here for real time
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(mktime(strptime(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))))
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! The first conversion has what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

make a time structure from a timetuple then use the structure to create a utc time

```
from datetime import datetime

def local_to_utc(local_st):
    time_struct = time.mktime(local_st)
    utc_st = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time_struct)
    return utc_st

d=datetime(2016,6,30,3,12,40,0)
timeTuple = d.timetuple()
print(local_to_utc(timeTuple))
```

output:

```
2016-06-30 09:12:40
```