# How to get timezone from Python C API?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I don't find anything to find the timezone from a `PyDateTime_DateTime`. I want to get either the offset or the timezone name if possible.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1111056/694576 ?

Comment: @alk: No, that's something different.

Answer (score 1):

There just isn't any C API accessor for a datetime's time zone. Your best option is to go through ordinary attribute access:

```
PyObject *tz_or_none = PyObject_GetAttrString(dt, "tzinfo");
```

Comment: I already got it by doing `auto o = ((PyDateTime_DateTime*)src.ptr())->tzinfo;` but then I don't know what to do

Comment: @EntrustName: If you're willing to pull out the undocumented implementation details of implementation details, sure, you can access struct members directly (and probably segfault in short order if it's a naive timezone). tzinfo objects don't have C API accessors for any of their data either, though, so you'll have to keep making assumptions and pulling out undocumented struct members manually if you're dead-set on avoiding normal attribute access and method calls.