# Get local time zone name on Windows (Python 3.9 zoneinfo)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo, python-3.9

Checking out the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) module in Python 3.9, I was wondering if it also offers a convenient option to retrieve the local time zone (OS setting) on Windows.

On GNU/Linux, you can do

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

naive = datetime(2020, 6, 11, 12)
aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('localtime'))
```

but on Windows, that throws

> ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key localtime'

so would I still have to use a third-party library? e.g.

```
import time
import dateutil

tzloc = dateutil.tz.gettz(time.tzname[time.daylight])
aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tzloc)
```

Since `time.tzname[time.daylight]` returns a localized name (German in my case, e.g. 'Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit'), this doesn't work either:

```
aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tzloc))
```

Any thoughts?

---

p.s. to try this on Python < 3.9, use `backports` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142350/10197418)):

```
pip install backports.zoneinfo
pip install tzdata # needed on Windows
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use zoneinfo to use the system local time zone. You can simply pass `None` (or omit) the time zone when calling [`datetime.astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

From the docs:

> If called without arguments (or with `tz=None`) the system local timezone is assumed. The `.tzinfo` attribute of the converted datetime instance will be set to an instance of timezone with the zone name and offset obtained from the OS.

Thus:

```py
from datetime import datetime

naive = datetime(2020, 6, 11, 12)
aware = naive.astimezone()
```

Comment: Does that work if daylight savings is different between the current date and the datetime you're trying to imprint?

Comment: @MarkRansom - Yes.

Comment: I just double checked and indeed you're right.  This is a great hidden feature!

Comment: This is not a 100% solution on Windows, for example on my system datetime.now().astimezone().strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%I%Z%z' ) produces "2023-05-31 12:49:12Central Daylight Time-0500" instead of "2023-05-31 12:49:12CDT-0500". However datetime.now().astimezone( zoneinfo.ZoneInfo( 'America/Chicago' )).strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%I%Z%z' ) produces the expected '2023-05-31 12:57:12CDT-0500'.

Comment: This doesn't give the official IANA time zone names

Answer (score 5):

While `astimezone(None)` is convenient, sometimes you might want to get the [IANA name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of the time zone your OS is configured to use. Be careful though, Windows does not use the IANA database; a mapping is required from "Windows time zone" to IANA identifier. That mapping might be wrong, see [Philip Couling's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048001/10197418).

[Version 4 of `tzlocal`](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) will also use `zoneinfo` for that whilst maintaining compatibility with `pytz` through the [deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/):

```
>>> import tzlocal
>>> print(tzlocal.get_localzone())
Europe/Berlin
>>> print(repr(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
_PytzShimTimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'), 'Europe/Berlin')
```

***[update]*** With version 5, the pytz deprecation shim is removed, see also [tzlocal's readme](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/blob/master/README.rst):

```py
>>> print(tzlocal.get_localzone())
Europe/Berlin
>>> print(repr(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin')
```

Comment: Be warned version 5 of tzlocal has changes that make it incompatible for use inside of a logging handler, see https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/issues/147

Comment: @royce3 thanks for the hint, haven't been using the module for a while. It seems to be a circular import bug, see https://github.com/jobec/rfc5424-logging-handler/pull/47

Comment: -1 What this answer is suggesting should be considdered as impossible.  The reasons are too complex to fit into a comment. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048001/453851).

Answer (score 2):

### The question is founded on a minunderstanding of timezones

*That's understandable; the topic is maddeningly complex, even for such trivially simple questions!*

The misunderstanding here is to believe `zoneinfo` can be related to MS Window's local timezones. It can't! They are two completely different things, even if they look alike:

- [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) Is for IANA timezones
- MS Windows does not use IANA timezones

Jon Skeet discusses it here: [IANA to Windows timezone mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873868/453851/).  The problem is not just about the names of the timezones, but their actual meaning.

#### What is a timezone?

Timezones don't really exist. The more you try to prove they exist, the more you find they really really don't exist.

Some humans observe different time on the clock to other humans. There have been attempts to catalogue which humans observe which times and how these all fit together. But these are political decisions and sometimes politics gets very messy.

When you try to catalog which humans observe which timezone, you will find cases were there is no right answer. Eg: [Lebinon in 2023](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/26/lebanon-awakes-to-two-times-of-day-amid-daylight-savings-dispute).

#### But I found a way to map them...

The main problem is that IANA (used by `zoneinfo`) is a seperate database to the one used by MS Windows.  While you can find many mappings between the two they don't necessarily coordinate with each other and so can really disagree on offsets.

**Really dangerously** you can find mappings that look like they match but suddenly and unexpectly disagree, so unless you are going to very carefully handle the conversion yourself, you shouldn't try to get the IANA name for an MS Windows configured timezone.

Comment: @FObersteiner that is to say, please don't leave SO over down votes or comments pointing out answers are incorrect. This is the only way this community can really function. The purpose is not to make personal attacks, but to swiftly communicate truth.

Comment: I have to add I'd actually give this a +1 because you take the time to *explain* what you consider wrong and why you vote - a bit of ambiguity there ;-) The issue I'm having is that I'm not convinced that this system works. I've been there myself, voting and commenting to point out assumed misconceptions of others. And I've been using the wrong tone there, which is not good if you want to communicate facts. And maybe I didn't get the whole picture after all? Besides, Matt's answer can be misleading as well; did you notice it sets a "tz" without rules?