# Is there a way to find the local timezone with datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I am trying to make some code that creates a clock using the user's local time with the datetime library.

```
import datetime as dt
import os
import time

z = dt.datetime.now()

def local_time():

    def time_check(t):
        if t < 10:
            t = "0{}".format(t)
        else:
            t = t
            
        return t

    p = dt.datetime.now()

    hour = p.hour
    minute = p.minute
    second = p.second 

    hour = time_check(hour)
    minute = time_check(minute)
    second = time_check(second)

    local_time = '{}:{}:{}'.format(hour, minute, second)
    return local_time

time_zone = z.timezone() 

for i in range(999999999999999999999):
    print("Time: {} {}".format(local_time(), time_zone))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("cls")
```

What I am doing is gathering the hour, minute, and second of the local time, and constantly updating it in the terminal, and deleting the previous time.
This works fine, but I am also trying to display the timezone of the user, and I am having a hard time trying to find a way to do it. Does anyone know a way? Thanks.

Comment: e.g. [Get local time zone name on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62330675/10197418); and see also [Python: Figure out local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720319/10197418). The easiest method is probably using `.astimezone(None)`, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

Answer (score 0):

Importing the *python-dateutil* library should make this easier. Install the library with the **pip install python-dateutil** command at the terminal if you don't have it installed beforehand. Once you do that, test the below code:

```
from datetime import *
from dateutil.tz import *

print(datetime.now(tzlocal()).tzname())
print(datetime(2021, 6, 2, 16, 00, tzinfo=tzlocal()).tzname())

#Output
#SA Western Standard Time
#SA Western Standard Time
```

Using *tzlocal()* and *tzname()* together will give you the current timezone. The *dateutil* library is very powerful and useful. Check out the full documentation [HERE](https://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Hopefully that helped.