# IANA to Windows timezone mapping

Tags: .net, timezone

I am trying to understand how to map IANA timezones to Windows timezones.
I did see various posts on here about TimeZoneConverter and I started to use it. However, there is one question which I did not find an answer for:

Since Window to IANA timezones are a one-to-many, if we convert from IANA to Windows, is there a chance that the actual offset and DST flag might be wrong. For example, is there a situatation where a Windows timezone covers 2 hours of time while IANA has two different timezones for each of those hours (of the two). This way if we take the IANA for the second hour and convert it to Windows timezone, the actual offset would be different/changes.

It is less important for us to be able to map from IANA -> Windows and then back to IANA to get same timezone name. It is very important that when we do the re-mapping, the actual offsets and DST flags do not change.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is very important that when we do the re-mapping, the actual offsets and DST flags do not change.

That's effectively requiring the Windows database and the IANA database to always be exactly in sync. While I can understand the desire, it's an unrealistic expectation. Aside from anything else, both databases change over time, as governments make changes to their rules. Unless you ensure that you change both versions at exactly the same time (on all machines you use!) there will always be the possibility of discrepancies. That's aside from the actual data being different in the stable state - which also happens.

If you look at the ICU mapping between Windows and IANA zones names (e.g. [this copy in the Noda Time repo](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/data/cldr/windowsZones-40.xml)) you'll see that it's not a 1:1 mapping. A single Windows time zone ID can map to several different IANA IDs, with one (territory 001) being deemed the primary mapping.

I'd expect that for the vast majority of the time, you'll see the same results between the two - but it's definitely not guaranteed for every instant in every time zone.

Comment: I think I might have worded that last portion slightly incorrectly. I think what you are saying that, excluding the situation where the timezone metadata is out of sync, we can safely assume that in 99.9% of the situations remapping will keep same offset/DST. Or written in another way, it is not a normal/standard situation to have some Windows timezone be mapped into multiple IANA timezones with some having different offsets/DST data. Is that correct?

Comment: @User20909: Well as I said, there *are* Windows time zones mapped to multiple IANA time zones. Many of those will only have different data in the past, but I make no guarantees. I'd expect the offsets to be the same for "present and future" in most places and most times - I'm not sure I'd go as far as a 99.9% expectation though.

Comment: Offsets should match consistently from 2010 forward.  DST flags are a different story, as Windows sometimes fakes a DST transition to handle one-time changes in standard offset.

Comment: Two poeple here make overly bold assumptions and [Lebinon steps up to the challenge](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/26/lebanon-awakes-to-two-times-of-day-amid-daylight-savings-dispute). Timezones are political and, eventually, the simple act of cataloging them becomes pollitical too. You can't assume two seperate TZ databases will harmonize unless they explicitly endevour to do so.